bathroom concrete floor patch type?
This old floor has some spalling but main concern is an area that looks like someone started jack hammering for about 3 feet long, 4 inches wide, uneven depth (max depth around 2").
Looking for some kind of filler for this area to level it off, it's not continuous but rather a couple of segments separated from each other.
Lots of products out there but most say depth of 1/4" layering, anyone know some product that can do the 2" all in one go?
This pic is just one of the areas I'm addressing.


This depends on the plan for the finished floor.
If it's tile or solid core LVP you can fill with thinset mortar, top bond or concrete patch.
If it is sheet vinyl you need a smoother surface and the concrete patch can be used for the deep areas with floor leveling compound over the entire floor to make it smooth.

Resin could also work here, assuming this is not gonna be the finished floor.
